# react native build error stops running .\gradlew assembleRelease

Tags: react-native

when i run **rebuildproject** in android studio it says it ran successfully but in tasks there are some errors:

```
:@react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugAidl
:@react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugRenderscript 
:react-native-snackbar:compileDebugAidl 
:react-native-snackbar:compileDebugRenderscript 
:@react-native-community_async-storage:packageDebugRenderscript 
:@react-native-community_async-storage:processDebugJavaRes  
:react-native-snackbar:packageDebugRenderscript 
:react-native-snackbar:processDebugJavaRes  
:react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugAidl 
:react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugRenderscript 
:react-native-vector-icons:packageDebugRenderscript 
:react-native-vector-icons:processDebugJavaRes  
:react-native-linear-gradient:compileDebugAidl  
:react-native-linear-gradient:compileDebugRenderscript  
:react-native-linear-gradient:processDebugJavaRes   
:react-native-linear-gradient:packageDebugRenderscript  
:react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugAidl  
:react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugRenderscript  
:react-native-gesture-handler:packageDebugRenderscript  
:react-native-gesture-handler:processDebugJavaRes   
:@react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugAidl   
:@react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugRenderscript   
:@react-native-community_netinfo:packageDebugRenderscript   
:@react-native-community_netinfo:processDebugJavaRes    
:@react-native-community_viewpager:compileDebugAidl 
:@react-native-community_viewpager:compileDebugRenderscript 
:@react-native-community_viewpager:packageDebugRenderscript 
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets 
:app:compileDebugAidl   
:app:compileDebugRenderscript   
:app:copyDebugBundledJs 
:@react-native-community_viewpager:processDebugJavaRes  
:app:processDebugJavaRes
```

these all have **stop signs** beside theme

i can run react-native run-android and **it runs** the project but **i can't build apk**
when i copy app-debug.apk in my phone it stops at the second page saying **can't connect to server**

when i run it in **emulator** or run **via usb** it **works** perfectly

i also get **uses or overrides a deprecated API.** with these libs

```
react-native-gesture-handler
@react-native-community/viewpager
```